# Pre-cache List of videos uisng CacheDataSource.Factory( ) android

Tags: android, caching, exoplayer, cache-control, media-source

I'm able to cache a playing video using the below code:

```
 ProgressiveMediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
                new CacheDataSource.Factory()
                        .setCache(SimpleMediaPlayer.simpleCache)
                        .setUpstreamDataSourceFactory(new DefaultDataSource.Factory(this,new DefaultHttpDataSource.Factory()))
                         .setFlags(CacheDataSource.FLAG_IGNORE_CACHE_ON_ERROR)
        ).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri("https://xxxxxx.s3.us-north-2.amazonaws.com/xxxxxx.mp4"));

        playerView.setPlayer(player);
        player.setMediaSource(mediaSource);
        player.prepare();
```

But I want a list of videos to cache before playing. I want to do this in background threads something like using WorkManager or Services. I need an efficient way to do that. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Workmanager to schedule background work for precache video data from URL  refer this :

https://www.section.io/engineering-education/preloading-and-buffering-videos-in-android-with-exoplayer/

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Are you telling me about the periodic work manager or one-time work manager? The periodic minimum wait time for the second call is 15 min. I think your suggestion is to call a one-time work manager after every fetch. I don't know an effective way to do that. Caching 15 videos within a parallel background thread? Please explain to me. I have already visited that site.